# Is controlling the colors in contourf possible?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure, contourf

[image]Good afternoon,
I have this code in which I would like to specify three colored regions. One is when the final function C and C1 merged together as shown in the code is either less than 0 , between 0 and 1, and when greater than 1. In the code i need the merged contourf plot to be in the end merged and defined in three simple regions. The outcome is shown in the following figure. You might think at first that okay the most dominant color is the bright blue but when you have a look at the contourf plot and the color bar they for some reason do not match. Thank you for your help. Apologizes to the admins for not posting this problem as a separate problem.

```
    [r,R] = meshgrid(0.1:0.01:10,-5:0.01:5);
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Z=(((R).^2)-1 );
           A=2+ (R.*(r+(1./r)));
           B=sqrt(Z).*(r-(1./r));
           Ratio=acoth(A./B);
           D= (r+(1./r))./4;
           E=D./sqrt(Z);

           C=D.*E.*Ratio;
    C(R==1)=(r(R==1)+(1./r(R==1)))*0.25.*((r(R==1).^2-1)./(2*r(R==1)+r(R==1).^2-1) );
    C(R==-1)=(r(R==-1)+(1./r(R==-1)))*0.25.*((r(R==1).^2-1)./(2*r(R==1)-r(R==1).^2+1) );
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    Z1=((1 -(R).^2));
           A1=2+ (R.*(r+(1./r)));
           B1=sqrt(Z1).*(r-(1./r));
           Ratio1=EA(A1./B1);
           D1= (r+(1./r))./4;
           E1=D1./sqrt(Z1);

           C1=D1.*E1.*Ratio1;
    C1(R==1)=(r(R==1)+(1./r(R==1)))*0.25.*((r(R==1).^2-1)./(2*r(R==1)+r(R==1).^2-1) );
    C1(R==-1)=(r(R==-1)+(1./r(R==-1)))*0.25.*((r(R==1).^2-1)./(2*r(R==1)-r(R==1).^2+1) );

    test=C;
    test((R<1)&(R>-1))=nan;   
    test1=C1;
    test1(R>1)=nan;
    test2=test1;
    test2(R<-1)=nan;

       figure
          contourf(r,R,test)
        hold on
         contourf(r,R,test2);
        colormap(jet(3))
        conts = [-1:1:2];
            h=colorbar;
         set(get(h,'ylabel'),'string','\gamma P_P L','FontSize',18)
           xlabel('$r$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',18)
        ylabel('$D \over 2\sqrt{M}$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',18)
    set(h,'YTick',conts)
    set(gca,'fontsize',18)
        hold off 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function  y  = EA(x)

 y = acot(x);

y(y<0)=y(y<0)+pi;

return


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image: Outcome of the code]

Comment: Spontaneously I would blame the data instead of the plot if you cannot see what you would like, apart from this I get an error in line 17 `Ratio1=EA(A1./B1);`. EA is not defined. Apart from this. You may have the wrong scale on the colorbar. Try to keep the numbers a little bit longer and see what values you get for contour. You can set both y limits c limits if you want.

Comment: There is another problem with `Ratio1 = EA(A1./B1)` - if `EA` is a variable, then using a division `A1./B1` as indices seems to be completely wrong. Are you 100% sure you always get positive integers from this division?

Comment: THank you gentlemen for the comments. I have added the function EA and hope that simplifies things. 
The values originally are from -inf to +inf but the thing is I want the color bar to show okay we have 3 regions: 
a- values less than 0
b- values between 0 and 1
c- values greater than 1
That is my aim, I would expect in terms of the y axis D/sqrt{M} that for r>1, region c is valid for -1<D/sqrt{M}<0 rest is divided between region (a) and (b)
I hope i clarified everything
thank you for your help

Comment: @AbedLibnanHaidar I began by testrunning your code and removing all the the `set` commands so that I would see the real scale used (which you was requested to do but obviously have not, _You may have the wrong scale on the colorbar. Try to keep the numbers a little bit longer ..._). I found the scale range was somewhere between (-200,200). I used `caxis` to set colorbar axis to [-1,1] (which I also suggested, _You can set both y limits c limits if you want_). This made the plot starting to look more like you described. This is what I can do since I do not know what result you are looking for.

Comment: @patrik thank you for your help. I know I have the wrong scale however the aim of the figure is to show how i would like the color bar to be matching exactly the contour plot: three regions where dark blue is any value below zero, values between 0 and 1 in bright blue, and last but not least yellow color for contour values greater than 1. I want each color to match exactly. My problem is if not doing so I would get 2 color dominance and having a color classified for just one point at -200 or 200 is just annoying

Comment: Ok my bad, Of course the problem is the contour levels. Try to edit these, `contourf(r,R,test, 'LevelList', [-inf,-1,0,1,inf]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so there are 2 major problems with the code.

1) The colorbar needs to be set to the right limits. This means, you need to set the xolorbar color scale to another value. The color limits of the colorbar is for the moment a property called `'Clim'` and is located in the axis in 2015b. These things may change, so I recommend using the function `caxis` for this. Since you have 3 colors and want ranges [-inf -> 0,0 -> 1,1 -> Inf]. I suggest a limit `caxis([-1,2]`);this will set the breaks where you need them.

2) The levels (which is what MATLAB calls the topological levels in the plot) are set automatically by MATLAB. These values does not correspond to what you want. Use the argument `contourf(r,R,test, 'ShowText', 'on')` and you will see what I mean. I am not sure if there is a built in function to modify these, but the property is called `LevelList` and is found in the contour plot object. You can use the following in the `contourf` functions

```
contourf(r,R,test, 'LevelList', [-inf,-1,0,1,inf]);
contourf(r,R,test, 'LevelList', [-inf,-1,0,1,inf]);
```

Comment: Just one minor issue, I was wondering how to make sure that when the contour is at -1 or 1, it does not give me a black line. Instead I want the color itself?

Comment: @AbedLibnanHaidar you can remove the lines, `contourf(r,R,test, 'LevelList', [-inf,-1,0,1,inf], 'LineStyle', 'none');`. In case you need to do a lot of modifications to the contour plot, you may want to use the plot handle `[data, hb] = contourf(...`. Then you can use the set command to set line style, `set(hb,'LineStyle', 'none'`. This goes for level list as well.